# Root systems and the possible angles between roots.

Tags: bilinear-form, root-systems

On page 4 of these notes by John Dusel (http://math.ucr.edu/~jmd/Root_Systems.pdf) it reminds us that if we have a symmetric positive bilinear form (pageg 2) we can define an angle between vectors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by asking that it satisfies $(\alpha ,\beta) = \lVert \alpha \rVert \lVert \beta \rVert \cos{\theta}$. However, it goes on to say that $\cos{^2\theta} = 1$ iff $\alpha = \pm \beta$. I'm not sure how this can be true though, as I think $\cos{^2\theta} = 1$ iff $\alpha = \pm \beta$ implies that $(\alpha ,\alpha) = (\beta ,\beta)$.

I'm guessing I'm missing something here?

Comment: I understand that the angle between $\alpha$ and $\pm \alpha$ is 0 or $\pi/2$. I just don't understand why there might not be another root whose inner product with $\alpha$ is 0, which isn't a multiple of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks, however, I understand that! The problem I am having is why we have $cos^2\theta = 1$ iff $\alpha = \pm \beta$. I think this only is true if $(\alpha, \alpha) = (\beta, \beta)$.

Comment: Said a different way, can there exist a $\beta$ such that $\beta \neq \pm \alpha$ but such that $(\alpha, \beta) =\lVert \alpha \rVert \lVert \beta \rVert$?

Comment: But that means that $\cos^2\theta = 1$ does not imply $\alpha = \pm \beta$!

Comment: If we were using the standard euclidean angle then I agree. However we are using the angle defined by our inner product.

Comment: How do we conclude from $(\alpha, \beta) = \lVert \alpha \rVert \lVert \beta \rVert$ that $\alpha = \pm \beta$?

Comment: we have an 'if and only if' statement. We assume that $cos\theta = \pm 1$  and want to show that $\alpha = \pm \beta$. So far we only have $(\alpha, \beta) = \pm \lVert \alpha \rVert \lVert \beta \rVert$. How do we get $\alpha = \pm \beta$ from there?

Comment: We get $\cos \theta=1$, so $\theta=0$. This means, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have zero angle. Hence $\beta=\pm \alpha$ (because our space is Euclidean).

Comment: How can we mathematically deduce that? For me the sentence 'they have zero angle so this means they are multiples' is coming out of thin air!